Is the following SNR and line attenuation good?
I'm trying to figure out if there is interference on my line. The wires that I spliced together one is solid copper for my DSL but the other is twisted pair and a few of them were so thin that fell off. So there is contact but not sure if I'm losing in terms of efficiency. Could someone tell me by the numbers if there is anything worrisome?


If you added a photo of the splice then perhaps we could say more than that the ratio of actual rate to attainable rate doesn't appear to be too bad.

I have it taped but basically there are 5 strands of wires of which only three are wrapped around the solid copper, the other two are short so who knows. My guess is that this is not a good thing but it is a bad wire. I guess upgrading to a proper solid wire should improve things either way.

The best way would be to connect the solid-core wires into a wall jack (take care to get the colours correct) and then use the appropriate cable plugged into that to go to the modem/router.
